# Recover a truecrypt volume after windows 7 setup created a hidden 100MB partition on it

Tags: disk-encryption

windows 7 setup created a hidden 100MB partition on a hard disk which was encrypted with Truecrypt.

Truecrypt fails to mount it now. Is there any way to rescue the rest of the files?

I was stupid enough not to make any backup.

I know this is similar to this 
https://serverfault.com/questions/114820/fix-a-truecrypt-volume

Answer (score 1):

Try restoring the volume header from the Tools menu (you may need to move the drive to another system that has Truecrypt installed).  Truecrypt stores a backup header at the end of the volume.

Of course, once you have your volume header restored, Truecrypt can mount it, but Windows won't.  You will now have the separate problem of trying to rebuild a file system with the first ~100MB overwritten.  You are likely going to need recovery utilities ([Piriform's Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) is one) to pull files off of it.